why don't they use HDMI cables to connect servers and computers

HDMI cables are used to transfer video data between 2 devices

considering that it can even transfer very high resolution video data(4k) at very high frame rates, i was thinking why dont we use it to connect computers

my intuition is that it must be faster than ethernet

is it even possible to transfer data between 2 computers using HDMI

what do they use to connect their computers in data centres



How long can an HDMI cable be? my intuition is that it must be faster than ethernet - wrong. HDMI 1.2a max speed is 48 Gbit/s, Ethernet's is 400 Gbit/s with 40 km reach.

Ethernet is a data transfer standard with rates from 10M up to 400G. (with some off-book links supporting Tbps) HDMI is designed for video.


why dont we use it to connect computers

There are really two questions here.

Why do we not use HDMI to connect computers.
Why do we not re-use HDMI cables to implement an interface for high speed connections between computers.


To answer the first question, HDMI is a derivative of DVI. HDMI/DVI are designed as a digital monitor interface, to transport raster data from a graphics source to a monitor.
They are not designed for bi-directional data communication. The cables themselves could technically be re-used but the rest of the technology stack would need to be redesigned.

considering that it can even transfer very high resolution video data(4k) at very high frame rates,

For reference, full HD at 60Hz is about 3 gigabits per second. 4K at 60Hz will be about 12 gigabits per second. And remember that is in one direction!

So why not re-use HDMI cables for a networking protocol.
Firstly, there has been a shift in the computing world. It used to be that designers of computer technologies used generic off the shelf connectors. Some computer technologies (and many industrial techonologies) still do. It was the user's resposibility to check
But, as computers have become more available to general folks, there has been an increasing move towards, "if it fits, it should work or at least not fry stuff". Newer computer standards like USB, DVI, SATA HDMI, Displayport have all used their own connectors. So users are prevented from screwing things up.
Sometimes manufacturers of low-volume devices do borrow connectors designed for a different purpose. For example, I've seen a PCIe expansion chassis that used a DVI connetor to carry PCIe, but this is very much frowned upon and not something a designer of a major standard is likely to do.
Secondly, the HDMI connector is non-locking. Traditionally network cables have been locking as it is considered undesirable if they are unplugged by accident.
Thirdly, HDMI cables and electrical signalling are designed for relatively short runs. Getting to a projector on the ceiling of the current room is often a stretch. Let alone getting to several rooms down the hall, and that is at mere "HD" resoloution. For 4K you are likely to require expensive active cables if you want to do more than hook up a computer or STB to a screen in the same peice of furniture.

is it even possible to transfer data between 2 computers using HDMI

Sure, you could put a graphics card with HDMI output in one computer and a HDMI capture card in another. And then write some software to transfer data. You would probablly need to do some experiments to see how much additional error checking and correction was needed. HDMI transmission isn't nessacerally error free.
But it would be a totally non-standard thing to do, and it would only carry data in one direction.

what do they use to connect their computers in data centres

Ethernet, but not nessacerally the same Ethernet you use at home.
A lot of datacenters, particularly at the smaller/cheaper end of the market find good old 1000BASE-T Ethernet sufficient for connecting to the individual computers.
When speeds greater than that are needed, there are multiple options. There is a 10GBASE-T standard for 10 Gbps over twisted pair, but it has a reputation for being power hungry and so many datacenter operators dislike it.
Many 10 Gbps devices, and practically all devices for speeds higher than 10 Gbps have modular transceiver slots. SFP+ for 10 Gbps, SFP28 for 25 Gbps, QSFP+ for 40 Gbps and QSFP28 for 100 Gbps and more exotic types for higher speeds. These slots can be used either to install a fiber transciever or, for short runs, they can be directly connected together with what is known as a "direct attach cable".

Funnily enough, there is "HDMI with Ethernet" which uses unused pins of the HDMI cable for Ethernet. Also, HDMI does have bi-directional features, but they are not symmetrical; the return channels have significantly lower bandwidth: there is ARC (audio return channel) which is intended to allow a TV to send audio back to a receiver, there is CEC which is intended to allow a TV to send control commands to a receiver, BluRay player, etc. for single-remote operations, and there's a display identification channel which informs the sending device about the capabilities of the screen.

A while ago, Dell used HDMI cables for switch stacking. Didn't stick though, apparently.

"Newer computer standards like USB, DVI, SATA HDMI, Displayport have all used their own connectors." – cough USB-C cough.
